# How to adjust the character sizes in math equation?

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

I'm trying to create a math cheat sheet but the problem is that the "+" sign is bigger than "n". The "ln" also at the last part its height looks very compressed. It's quite annoying. How can I adjust this?

[image]

Comment: Are you in \textstyle or \displaystyle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the material in the fractional terms looks too small/compressed, the best solution is to switch to display-style fractions, using the `\dfrac` macro that's provided by the `amsmath` package.

In the following screenshot, the `array` on the left contains `\dfrac` instructions, whereas the `array` on the right does not.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{document}
\[
% first array with \dfrac directives
\begin{array}{l}
\int u^n \, du = \dfrac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}+C\\
\int \tfrac{1}{u}\,du = \ln\lvert u\rvert+C\\
\int e^u\, du = e^u + C\\
\int a^u\, du = \dfrac{1}{\ln a}a^u+C\\
\end{array}\qquad
% second array without \dfrac directives
\begin{array}{l}
\int u^n \, du = \frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}+C\\
\int \tfrac{1}{u}\,du = \ln\lvert u\rvert+C\\
\int e^u\, du = e^u + C\\
\int a^u\, du = \frac{1}{\ln a}a^u+C\\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of using `\dfrac`, I would apply `\displaystyle` to the entire equation. Otherwise, there is a disparity between the cramped looking integrals on the left and the big fractions on the right.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen - Thanks. I had actually contemplated pursuing the very solution you've suggested. However, I chose not to implement it, as I suspect that OP *wants* the "cheat sheet" to be chock-full with formulas, i.e., the OP will want it to look cramped. Honestly, if this were my document, I'd use a two-column `array` environment and omit all `\int`, `du`, and `+C` material. And, of course, I'd use automatic `\displaystyle` mode in both columns. :-)

Comment: Well, at least now the OP knows both options and can choose between them.

Comment: isn't there a "medium sized" fraction available from one of the (non-`amsmath`) packages?  (sorry, the system i'm on won't let me search in the site.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks. There's the `nccmath` package, which provides various macros for medium-sized math operators, fractions, and so on. E.g., the size of a fraction produced by `\mfrac` is about half-way between the sizes produced by `\tfrac` and `\dfrac`. I'm afraid I'm not all that familiar with the `nccmath` package. If the OP would like to get more information about `nccmath`'s offers, he/she may want to ask a new, separate question.

Comment: thanks, @Mico.  i'm not all that familiar with that package either, but think that medium-sized fractions would be much more appropriate in this context.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Let's see if the OP weighs and and clarifies his/her formatting needs.